# Changing UILabel alignment

Tags: rubymotion, formotion

Is there a way to align the UILabel when using Formotion forms?

I asked this question on Formotion GitHub project, pasting more details here - https://github.com/clayallsopp/formotion/issues/181

In this case I want to right align the UILabel.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you trying to align the labels for each field, or the text in each field? "field UILabel" kinda confused me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [text_alignment](https://github.com/clayallsopp/formotion/blob/5a09385703ef0be252d6367db8580eb538cbaeb3/app/app_delegate.rb#L150) option

There is also the `textAlignment` property on UITextField (`@form.row(:email).text_field.textAlignment`), which you can set to `NSTextAlignmentRight`

If you're trying to align the cell's label, you will likely just have to change the frames of the cell's subviews.